# getInfoContentsが呼ばれない

Tags: android, google-maps

現在、Google Map上のマーカーをタップした時にinfoWindowを表示させ、次にそのinfoWindowをタップすると別のカスタムinfoWindowを表示させようとしているのですが、マーカーをタップして出てきたinfoWindowをタップしてもsetOnInfoWindowClickListener内のgetInfoContents()が呼ばれず、カスタムinfoWindowが表示されません。なぜでしょう？（getInfoContents()が複数あるから……とか？）下記にマーカー部分に関するコードを載せます。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(company).snippet(address);
        mMap.addMarker(options);

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        Log.v("--->", "markerClicked");
                        return setInfoWindow(R.layout.marker_normal_window, R.id.simple_title, false, marker);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                        Log.v("--->", "infowindowClicked");
                        return setInfoWindow(R.layout.marker_detail_window, R.id.title, true, marker);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setInfoWindowAdapter を呼ぶのは一度にして、InfoWindow がクリックされたかどうかの状態を別に管理し、その状態に従って getInfoWindow の中で処理を切り替えることで実現できます。

```
private boolean mClicked;

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            TextView view = new TextView(MapsActivity.this);
            view.setText(marker.getTitle());
            view.setTextSize(40.f);
            if (mClicked) { // InfoWindow がクリックされた後
                view.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0x00, 0x00, 0x99));
            } else { // InfoWindow がクリックされる前
                view.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0x99, 0x00, 0x00));
            }
            return view;
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            mClicked = false; // まだ InfoWindow はクリックされていません
            // false を返すことで、自動的に InfoWindow が表示されます
            return false;
        }
    });
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            mClicked = true;
            marker.hideInfoWindow();
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    });
}
```

InfoWindow は getInfoWindowContents から View を返すことでカスタマイズできますが、実際は View を画像に変換した上で表示されます。ですので、InfoWindow 上の View にイベントを結びつけることはできませんし、View の参照を保持しておいて書き換えても画面上反映されません。onInfoWindowClick の中で一旦 InfoWindow を非表示にして、すぐ表示しなおしています。これにより、getInfoContents が再度呼ばれます。

上の例では TextView の文字色を切り替えているだけですが、適宜書き換えてください。

Comment: ご指摘の通りsetInfoWindowAdapterを呼ぶのを一度にして、上記を参考にコードを書いたところ、思う通りの動作を実現することができました！本当にありがとうございます！